# Error when I use placeholder as date

Tags: python, date, datetime, integer

I define my date-window of my code like this

```
import pandas as pd
#####
end   = datetime.datetime.now()
end   = end.date()
start = end - days * pd.tseries.offsets.BDay()
start = start.date()
```

And use it like so

```
print('After analysing from %s to %s' %(datetime.date(start), datetime.date(end)))
print('Duration: %1.1f Years ~ %d workdays - Extent: %d strategies and %d tickers' '\n'
'The following matrix of tickers and strategies show highest potential:' %(years, days, len(strategies), len(stocklist))
)
```

But I get an error

```
    print('After analysing from %s to %s' %(datetime.date(start), datetime.date(end)))

TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.date)
```

Does anyone know how I can use the dates properly? Thanks, my search here has returned nothing that I can understand.

Comment: Can you not just use  `% (start, end)` since these are already `datetime` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in trying to create a `datetime` object from a `datetime` object (`datetime.date` expects to receive integer year, month and day arguments). Since `datetime` objects know how to represent themselves as strings anyway, you can just use:

```
...'from %s ...' % start
```

and so on. For example,

```
In [183]: end   = datetime.datetime.now()

In [184]: end
Out[184]: datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 11, 14, 56, 32, 77665)

In [185]: str(end)
Out[185]: '2016-02-11 14:56:32.077665'

In [186]: end.date()
Out[186]: datetime.date(2016, 2, 11)

In [188]: '%s' % end.date()
Out[188]: '2016-02-11'
```

Alternatively, (if you haven't extracted the date-only part from `end`), you can use `strftime`:

```
In [189]: '%s' % end.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
Out[189]: '2016-02-11'
```

Comment: Well in using this answer I get an ugly blot with both date AND timestamp. I was looking for just the date.

Comment: Are you sure you're passing `end` to your string _after_ `end = end.date()`? See my edit.